# How to do this simple set of nearly identical js without so much repeating?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to learn DRY coding and wondering how to do this sort of thing with a lot less code.

ie I have something like this:

```
var option_shipping = $('#option_shipping div.selected .tag').text(),
    option_payment = $('#option_payment div.selected .tag').text(); 

if(option_shipping.length < 1) {

    error = 1;  

    $('.option_shipping_wrap').addClass('attention');

}

if(option_payment.length < 1) {

    error = 1;

    $('.option_payment_wrap').addClass('attention');

}
```

What is the most minimal way something like this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you using jQuery, you can make a little plugin for your needs:

```
jQuery.fn.checkShipping = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        var txt = jQuery(this).find('div.selected .tag').text(),
            wrapId = this.id+'_wrap';
        if (!txt.length) {
            error = 1;
            jQuery('#'+wrapId).addClass('attention');
        }
    });
};
```

then you can call it anywhere, and enjoy the advantages of chaining:

```
$('#option_shipping, #option_payment').checkShipping().hide().doSomethingElse();
```

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
function checkLengthError(obj_type) {
    var option = $('#option_'+obj_type+' div.selected .tag').text()
    if(option.length < 1) {
        error = 1;  
        $('.option_'+obj_type_'_wrap').addClass('attention');
    }
}
checkLengthError('shipping');
checkLengthError('payment');
```

In general, you should be looking for what's repetitive, and what's not. You repeat the actions being done on the DOM objects, but you're just switching what object's being manipulated - so figure how to "globalize" the reference to the object so that a variable for example can change what object is being accessed, and that variable (or argument, in this case) would only be changed once to do the whole job on a different object.

In short, only 'shipping' and 'payment' was the difference here, so in my example I just made sure I can change those to whatever I need and dumped everything in a function that can easily be accessed and modified to avoid repetition of code and repetitive editing when you wanna change something.

Comment: I see. Thats pretty good! Actually the other things differ more than just the shipping and payment in the rest of the form I'm validating, but essentially I could make the line var option = obj_type right? and then I could do 'checkLengthError('$('whatever').text()'); ?

Comment: Sure, that works. You can squid around with the code as you please, this is just an example. Good luck "dry-coding" :)

Comment: another +1 for "looking for what's repetitive"

Answer (score 1):

try this (if every item has a prefix of option_ you can even shorten this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var arr = [ "option_shipping", "option_payment", ... ]; var error = 0;
    $.each(arr,function(index, item)
    {
        if ($('#'+item+' div.selected .tag').text().length < 1) {
                    error++;
                    $('.'+item+'_wrap').addClass('attention');
                }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this ...

```
function BringAttentionTo(optionName) {
    var text = $('option_' + optionName + ' div.selected .tag').text();
    if (text.length < 1) {
        $('.option_' + optionName + '_wrap').addClass('attention');
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

if (BringAttentionTo('shipping')) error = 1;
if (BringAttentionTo('payment')) error = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). In this case you have to write almost no code for the actual validation but just define some rules.

Comment: Well, he's asking how to simplify code, I'm pretty sure he wants to learn how to do it, not find easy ways around the problem :P

Comment: Thanks for that. This form uses options that aren't form inputs though and I don't think it works for this scenario to my knowledge. Does it have scope for validating whether say 1 of 2 div tags has a 'selected' class?

Comment: AFAIK not. However, usually it's a good idea to have custom form widgets backed by real form elements such as hidden checkboxes or hidden fields...